# WPF TextBlock memory leak when using Font

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using .NET 4.5 on Windows 7, and might find a memory leak.
I have a `TextBlock` (not `TextBox` - it's not the Undo problem), which changes its value every second (CPU usage, time, etc...).
Using `.NET Memory Profiler` (and by simply watching task manager) I noticed the memory keeps on growing. To be more accurate, I see more and more live instances of `UnmanagedMemoryStream` (I tried `GC.Collect()` which obviously didn't do anything).

After some tests, I've found out that this problem appears only when I'm setting the `TextBlock` font to a resource font as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="#CCCCCC"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/MyUIControls;component/./Fonts/#Noto Sans"/>
</Style>
```

I tried updating the `Text` property directly from code or via Binding, it behaves the same for both ways.

Bottom line:
When the `FontFamily` is set, instances of `UnmanagedMemoryStream` keep on coming (forever) each time I'm updating the text. When I don't (set the `FontFamily` property), memory is stable.
(BTW, it happens when I use `Label` instead of `TextBlock` as well)

It looks like a memory leak but I couldn't find any reference about it.
Any suggestions of how can it be solved?

Comment: I know that it's an old question, but out of curiosity - have you tried to put the font resource into the app resource dictionary? Does it leak as well? `<FontFamily x:Key="AppFont">pack://application:,,,/MyUIControls;component/./Fonts/#Noto Sans</FontFamily>` and then use it `<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource AppFont}" />`

Comment: As @Endrju 's suggestion essentially creates a singleton of that font family object hold in a resource dict, it sould solve the memory issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A `FontFamily` leaks `UnmanagedMemoryStreams` when it is used if it was sourced from an embedded resource or a relative path. When the `FontFamily` is sourced from a system font or absolute path, it does not leak.

You can look [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/802663/wpf-fontfamily-leaks-unmanagedmemorystream-for-families-from-resources-or-relative-paths) and download the project that reproduces the problem.

**Workaround**: For Resource fonts: save fonts into a temporary folder and use the absolute path to the stored font.
For relative path fonts: resolve and use the absolute path instead.

Comment: Weird. Is that a bug or can you dispose the font?

Comment: @Aron : Look in the comments of the wpf team they say it is

Comment: Holy Moly, and they aren't gonna fix it (focus bugs with higher impact) which actually means: focus on bugs developers can notice more easily...

Comment: Is it possible to use custom fonts as Resource with absolute path? Or we should forget to use custom fonts as an embedded resource in general?

Comment: The link to the project that reproduces the problem is broken. I can't find it on Microsoft Connect. Anyone got a working link or can show how to reproduce?

Comment: I have tried to come up with an alternative solution via `AddFontMemResourceEx` as detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964801/wpf-use-font-installed-with-addfontmemresourceex-for-process-only

Comment: There's now an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/7289) on the WPF GitHub page. I suggest anyone affected by this bug give it a thumbs up. The author made a project that reproduces the bug: https://github.com/kitgrose/wpf-font-embed-leak