# What causes UnmanagedMemoryStream in WPF (Memory Leak)?

Tags: .net, wpf, memory-leaks, memory-profiling, resource-loading

Profiling my .NET Application shows me that there is a big delta in [UnmangedMemoryStreams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream.aspx).

It seems they are created from some resource loading.

Anyone has an idea what can cause this loading or how to debug this?

Screenshots from Profiling:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/eO76W]

[image: http://imgur.com/a/eO76W]

Comment: What assemblies are you loading? Little code details will help

Comment: @DarkKnight: It's a big project with lots of assemblies. At meantime i found that a Timer updating a label causes the leak. Maybe this link describes my problem, not sure yet... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452443/wpf-textblock-memory-leak-when-using-font

Comment: even this leaks:            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="50"
                   Style="{x:Null}"
                   Text="{Binding CurrentTime, Mode=OneWay}"/> ... where CurrentTime (string) is set via Timer - Timer itself is not leaking, it's the XAML thing

Comment: Yep. FontFamily set by some Style is causing the leak. Style="{x:Null}" does not fix it, FontFamily must be set directly like FontFamily="Arial" on the TextBlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said in the comments, FontFamily is causing the leak. More details:
[WPF TextBlock memory leak when using Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452443/wpf-textblock-memory-leak-when-using-font)