# WPF load font from Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, resources

So after quick search i found this solution:

I have inside my `Resources` folder fond called `Abstract`.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="Abstract">
       <Setter Property="Label.FontFamily" Value="Resources/#Abstract" />
   </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And my `Label`:

```
<Label Name="lblValue"
       Content="Value"                                
       Style="{DynamicResource Abstract}"
       FontSize="14"/>
```

And nothing happening, i just cannot see the `font` i want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39912794/17034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's a memory leak you need to be aware of.**

Any font reference which uses a relative path will cause a memory leak.
The way to do this is to use an absolute path.
And yes, that is a nuisance.

See this:
[WPF TextBlock memory leak when using Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452443/wpf-textblock-memory-leak-when-using-font)

I've recently been working on something which uses fancy fonts and investigated the issue. It's still there with .net 4.7.
I wouldn't use a temporary folder, deliver your ttf to the same folder as your exe or into local appdata if you have several apps which will use the same ttf.

My plan, when I get round to this specific aspect of our app, is to write a custom markup extension which will allow me to pass a short name and go find the absolute path on the user's machine. I'll be using appdata.

Your immediate problem is because you're not using a relative path. Put a / in front of your path there.

Value="/Resources/#Abstract"

But you will then have a memory leak.

Comment: Finally this work using this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453640/how-to-include-external-font-in-wpf-application-without-installing-it/39912794#39912794 with the first way - Package with Application, this also lead to memory leak ?

Comment: Yes. The only way to avoid it is to have an absolute path. Unless the path you use starts something like "C:\..." then it will cause a memory leak.

Comment: What exactly is absolute path ?

Comment: A path which starts "C:\" is absolute. If you don't have a drive letter on the front of your path then it isn't absolute.

Comment: All the paths I see in that thread you linked are relative. EG new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ is relative to your application. You can't put them into file manager and find the file.