# Changing font type of one column in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in my WPF application.

I want the 3rd column to use a specific font type (so i can display some symbols there)

```
<Datagrid
...
>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="c1" Binding="{Binding Path=C1}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="c2" Binding="{Binding Path=C2}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="c3" Binding="{Binding Path=C3}" CellStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</Datagrid>
```

The MyStyle is in the control resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Resources/#MyFont" />
    </Style>
    ...
</USerControl.Resources>
```

what am i doing wrong? I have the MyFont.ttf file in the Resources folder. In the grid all columns are with the same font.

Comment: make sure that font is referenced properly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37278080/1506454. font name maybe different from file name

Answer (score 0):

When you fix the path, **you will have a memory leak.**
Using relative paths with fonts creates a memory leak.
You need an absolute path.
Installing the font is way simpler.
[WPF TextBlock memory leak when using Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452443/wpf-textblock-memory-leak-when-using-font)

If you can't do that then deliver it to appdata, work out the path and then add a resource pointing to that path. 
If your path doesn't start with a drive letter then it's almost certainly relative.