# WPF: Use font installed with 'AddFontMemResourceEx' for process only

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, gdi

In WPF we would like to use `ttf` fonts as embedded resources without copying or installing these to the system and without actually writing these to disk. Without memory leak issues.

None of the solutions detailed in:

[How to include external font in WPF application without installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453640/how-to-include-external-font-in-wpf-application-without-installing-it)

are useable in this scenario due to the WPF memory leak around this:

[WPF TextBlock memory leak when using Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452443/wpf-textblock-memory-leak-when-using-font)

Installing fonts from memory and process only is possible in GDI via [AddFontMemResourceEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183325(v=vs.85).aspx) . Since this installs the font for the process, it should work for WPF as well, but there seems to be issues around the `FontFamily` that we get after installing the font via `AddFontMemResourceEx`. E.g.:

```
var font = new FontFamily("Roboto");
```

This works in that it does not give any errors, but the font isn't actually changed, some line spacing and other metrics are changed, but the font looks exactly like `Segoe UI` for some reason.

The question is then is it and how is it possible to use fonts installed with `AddFontMemResourceEx` in WPF?

PS: Here the P/Invoke code:

```
const string GdiDllName = "gdi32";
[DllImport(GdiDllName, ExactSpelling= true)]
private static extern IntPtr AddFontMemResourceEx(byte[] pbFont, int cbFont, IntPtr pdv, out uint pcFonts);

public static void AddFontMemResourceEx(string fontResourceName, byte[] bytes, Action<string> log)
{
    var handle = AddFontMemResourceEx(bytes, bytes.Length, IntPtr.Zero, out uint fontCount);
    if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        log?.Invoke($"Font install failed for '{fontResourceName}'");
    }
    else
    {
        var message = $"Font installed '{fontResourceName}' with font count '{fontCount}'";
        log?.Invoke(message);
    }
}
```

This code succeeeds with log messages like:

```
Font installed 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' with font count '1'
```

Support code for loading embedded resource as byte array:

```
public static byte[] ReadResourceByteArray(Assembly assembly, string resourceName)
{
    using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        int read = 0;
        while (read < bytes.Length)
        {
            read += stream.Read(bytes, read, bytes.Length - read);
        }
        if (read != bytes.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                $"Resource '{resourceName}' has unexpected length " +
                $"'{read}' expected '{bytes.Length}'");
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Which means installing embedded fonts can be done like, with `assembly` being the assembly containing the embedded font resources and `EMBEDDEDFONTNAMESPACE` being the namespace of the embedded resources e.g. `SomeProject.Fonts`:

```
var resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

string Prefix = "EMBEDDEDFONTNAMESPACE" + ".";
var fontFileNameToResourceName = resourceNames.Where(n => n.StartsWith(Prefix))
    .ToDictionary(n => n.Replace(Prefix, string.Empty), n => n);

var fontFileNameToBytes = fontFileNameToResourceName
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => ReadResourceByteArray(assembly, p.Value));

foreach (var fileNameBytes in fontFileNameToBytes)
{
    AddFontMemResourceEx(fileNameBytes.Key, fileNameBytes.Value, log);
}
```

Comment: If you only load the font once (as a shared resource), you shouldn't leak that much. Your program will just eat a bit more memory (*if* that memory leak issue is still there, the reproducing project is gone with the Microsoft connect site)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but I got a solution where you can use your fonts as a `Resource` in your solution.

1. Declare all `fonts` you want as `Resource`.
2. Make a custom `MarkupExtension` called `FontExplorer`
3. Try my `XAML` Example

When the `application` starts and the `FontExplorer` is used for the first time, it caches all `fonts` which you have as resource. After that, everytime you need one of it, the cache is used to give it back.

### [image: Resources]

```
public class FontExplorer : MarkupExtension
{
    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Properties
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region Properties

    // ##########################################################################################
    // Public Properties
    // ##########################################################################################

    public string Key { get; set; }

    // ##########################################################################################
    // Private Properties
    // ##########################################################################################

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, FontFamily> _CachedFonts = new Dictionary<string, FontFamily>();

    #endregion


    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Constructor
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region Constructor

    static FontExplorer()
    {
        foreach (FontFamily fontFamily in Fonts.GetFontFamilies(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/"), "./Fonts/"))
        {
            _CachedFonts.Add(fontFamily.FamilyNames.First().Value, fontFamily);
        }            
    }

    #endregion

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // methods
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region methods

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return ReadFont();
    }

    private object ReadFont()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Key))
        {
            if (_CachedFonts.ContainsKey(Key))
                return _CachedFonts[Key];
        }

        return new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS");
    } 

    #endregion
}
```

---

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindow}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="local:MainWindow">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{local:FontExplorer Key='Candle Mustard'}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Switch" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{local:FontExplorer Key=Roboto}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World" FontFamily="{local:FontExplorer Key='Candle Mustard'}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World" FontFamily="{local:FontExplorer Key=Roboto}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Panel"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool Switch
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(SwitchProperty);
        set => SetValue(SwitchProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Switch"/> DependencyProperty.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SwitchProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Switch", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));


    private readonly DispatcherTimer _Timer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
        _Timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Switch = !Switch;
            Panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock {Text = "I'm frome code behind"});
            if(Panel.Children.Count > 15)
                Panel.Children.Clear();
        };
        _Timer.Start();
    }


    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // PropertyChanged
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region PropertyChanged

    /// <summary>
    /// The PropertyChanged Eventhandler
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raise/invoke the propertyChanged event!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

---

#### Preview

As you can see in the preview, the `memory usage` reduces from 83,2MB to 82,9 MB after the `GC` does it's job.

[image]

Comment: I tried this solution and it still leaked UnmanagedMemoryStream. I don't think the test just with the memory usage was valid; you need to actually test with a memory profiler too (which I did). However, if you change the static FontExporer constructor to create an absolute path to the font files, (and include the font files as "Content" rather than "Resource"), the leak does disappear.