# How can I import and implement new font in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a font imported to a folder named "fonts" I am trying to implement it to a label, but I don't know how to add it to the font family

```
FontFamily fam = (Uri("pack://firstwpfapp:,,,/fonts/DigitalFont.TTF", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453640/how-to-include-external-font-in-wpf-application-without-installing-it

Comment: Always resolve and use an absolute path for any font. If it doesn't start with a drive letter and you can paste it into file manager then it isn't absolute. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452443/wpf-textblock-memory-leak-when-using-font