# Set FontFamily from CodeBehind from Resources in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, font-family

hi i want change fontfamily from codebehind but my font is a resource style
how can i do this?

this is my fontDictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <FontFamily x:Key="IRANSans">IRANSans, pack://application:,,,/PersianCalendar;component/Resources/Fonts/Fonts/#IRANSans</FontFamily>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

in xaml i can set font this way:

```
FontFamily="{StaticResources IranSans}"
```

but i dont know how i can do this in codebehind, i want something like this

```
pt.FontFamily = new FontFamily(TryFindResources("IranSans"));
```

Comment: Relative path for fontfamily will give you a memory leak. https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/746 .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452443/wpf-textblock-memory-leak-when-using-font?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access to app resources by using the `Application.Current.Resources`

Try this:

```
pt.FontFamily = Application.Current.Resources["IRANSans"] as FontFamily;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `var fontFamily = this.Resources["IRANSans"];`